# SQL SERVER date/time inconsistency

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, datetime-format

I have a field in SQL Server with datatype of Datetime. I'm selecting the date simply as

```
select impDate from tbl1
```

What's happening is - the am/pm part is not consistent...Please see image

[image]

As can be seen - it seems to work fine for everything under 12:00 and over until it gets to 12:59 - at this point each hour is recognized as AM - when 2:46 and 3:17 should be PM.

This is what it looks like in sql server...

> 2016-10-18 10:25:16.000

EDIT:

> DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Comment: why should be 3:17 be `PM`?, you just posted some datetimes and told us it's not consistent

Comment: i don't understand your problem... row ordering is not guaranteed without an order by.

Comment: I just added an item and selected it from the table and it showed 2:01 AM

Comment: So?, that doesn't clarify anything. What value did you add?

Comment: @Kritner - it's not row ordering it's the issue with AM/PM. It supposed to show PM but shows AM

Comment: Sounds to me like the time being added to this table is putting in a date/time that is 12 hours off.  If you're using sysdate or getdate check the server time and database time, my guess is one of the 2 is 12 hours off.  Put another way: What is the time on the SQL database.  (translate it to 24 hour notation or be sure to include AM/PM.  also what is the time on teh SERVEr running the SQL server...

Comment: "As can be seen - it seems to work fine for everything under 12:00 and over until it gets to 12:59"  We can't see ***anything*** you've only given us random rows that have no context to your problem

Comment: @Kritner - I'm showing you an example of data that isn't being displayed correctly. If its such an unclear question then please go ahead and downvote it if you haven't already. xQbert seems to obviously not have as much of a difficulty understanding it as much as you do.

Comment: you are probably doing something like `insert into myTable (myDate) values '2016-11-10 3:30:00` for 3:30pm, when you actually want `insert into myTable (myDate) values '2016-11-10 15:30:00` (as an example)

Comment: Can you add some context? Why are the datetimes not correct? What were you expecting and why? How are these datetime values added and from what original source? Anything that can give us a better idea as to why you think there is a problem would be helpful.

Comment: @bobski, you've only shown us random rows of data, not why and how they're wrong.  How is the data getting into the database?  Why do you think it's wrong?  I understand you're saying "3:30 am from the database should say 3:30 pm" but that doesn't tell us why you think that.  Show us with code, not with out of context data.

Comment: @igor - for each date after 12:59pm - it's showing as AM - so as in the example if I enter a record into the table it will show 2:11 AM (I'm EST) instead of 2:11Pm

Comment: @Bobski - can you show us code or sql for how you are inserting these records into the table? An example with a value would be even more beneficial.

Comment: @bobski ***how*** are you entering the data that you would expect to be PM into the database

Comment: You should be using `HH` which is military time: `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` should be `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`. But how are you inserting this into the database? This just shows how you display the current date and time.

Comment: @kritner shows in EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to take a guess based on the information in the question that you are using the string value of the current date and time using `hh` to retrieve the hours which is a 12 hour format. If you use string concatination to build up your sql (*really bad, you should use parameters)* this would explain the problem.

However, the fix is not to use military time to insert the date but to use a parameterized query and pass the DateTime instance directly to the value of the parameter.

---

Here is a quick example of how to use a parameter to avoid this type of issue in the future.

```
Public Function SomeFunction(ByVal dateToInsert As DateTime)
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (impDate) VALUES(@impDate)"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@impDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateToInsert
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I've used parameters. I follow what previous programmers have done so I'm basically doing the same thing as them.

Comment: @Bobski - what language are you using? If its c# I have a ready example that could help you.

Comment: I'm using vb.net -

Comment: @Bobski - my vb is a little rusty but I think this should work (not sure about return type on the function though).

Comment: Pfft look at Igor linking to the documentation like some sort of badass

Answer (score 3):

```
// standard (must provide AM/PM, AM assumed if not explicitly provided)
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

vs

```
// military (24 hour clock)
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Perhaps a more important thing to take into account is, you should not be inserting `strings` into a `datetime`, you should be inserting `datetimes`.  Your `ToString()` implies that is what you're inserting into the database, which is part of where the problem stems from.

Keep data types the correct data type, and that will eliminate the issue.

Comment: no problem, a lot of the confusion could have been avoided if you showed the C# code that was performing the incorrect inserts from the get go :D  remember, we don't have any context to your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask